# XML Schema enumeration for large set of possible values

Tags: xml, enums, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I am trying to make an enumerated element that should have all possible regions (local, national, international) in the world (or as a start Canada should be fine) I have been searching for a way to do that but the only way I found was manually inputting all possible values by hand.

Is there another way to make my simpleType element only accept regions (local, national internationl)?

```
<xs:simpleType name="region">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Algoma"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Brant"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Bruce"/>
        ...
        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Well, you have to specify/define the regions somewhere... An XSD-Schema might be considered to be the right place. Or where else do you expect to place the names of the `local, national, international` items?

Answer (score 0):

There has been a lot of work done on this: see the UBL Code List methodology

https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/ciq/200704/pdf00000.pdf